# 2 cards: PCI-E 3.0 and 2.0 in PCI-E 3.0 slots. Will both work as PCI-E 2.0?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I am going to use 2 PCI-E cards in the same motherboard: one card is PCI-E 3.0 (8 lanes), another one is PCI-E 2.0 (8 lanes). MB is "MSI Z97 GAMING 5" which supports x8/x8 mode for lane splitting.
Will they work as:

1. 8 lane PCI-E **3.0** + 8 lane PCI-E **2.0** ?
2. 8 lane PCI-E **2.0** + 8 lane PCI-E **2.0** ?
3. Is there any other possibilities how it will work?

I do not have both PCI-E cards yet so I could try it myself, the question is still which card to buy, so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is. The question is however whether because of the compatibility for 2.0 card another 3.0 card will have to work as 2.0 too or will it work as 3.0?

Comment: What type of PCI-E cards are you putting in? In the configuration you're talking about each PCI-E device will have 8 lanes. One of them will run PCI-E 3.0 x8 and the other will run PCI-E 2.0 x8.

Comment: I am going to use 2 HBAs to create storage PC (home made NAS, so to speak), and I am going to use Adaptec HBA with PCI-E 3.0 support (because I am already have it) in first PCI-E slot. Also I wanted to buy LSI SAS 9201 for the second PCI-E slot (because it is cheep), but it is PCI-E 2.0. I just was afraid whether using 2.0 PCI-E HBA in second slot will cause performance deterioration to the first one (downshift of Adaptec performance from PCI-E 3.0 to work as PCI-E 2.0). In the case it might be better to sell Adaptec and buy two LSI SAS 9201...

Comment: I have checked it with PCI-E 3.0 video card and PCI-E 2.0 controller in second slot. [DrZoo](https://superuser.com/users/482362/drzoo) has gave a correct answer which is answer number 1. in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is 1. - Two cards will work as 8 lane PCI-E 3.0 + 8 lane PCI-E 2.0. I have checked it with PCI-E 3.0 video card and PCI-E 2.0 controller in second PCI-E 3.0 slot. Thank you [DrZoo](https://superuser.com/users/482362/drzoo)!